# is "in order to" a prepositional phrase?

Tags: phrases

is "In order to" a prepositional sentence starter? I use IEW writing curriculum, which requires one in my reports, but my teacher(aka my mother; I'm homeschooled) isn't sure.

Comment: [*In order to*](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/infinitive3d.html) indicate you've done some research, please indicate why you think you wouldn't be able to start a sentence with it? ;) Do you have something in mind that you're not sure of?

Comment: _In order to_ is a fixed phrase that can almost always be inserted (instead of merely _to_) in infinitive purpose phrases, like _He stopped to smoke_, which means _He stopped in order to smoke_, and **not** _He stopped smoking_. If you want to call it a preposition, go ahead. It's not an ordinary one, but some folks like labels on everything.